# How to work around the bug which prevents custom menus from being deleted?

Tags: customization, menus

A bug makes it impossible to delete a custom menu in the expected way: select menu, click Delete Menu. This has never worked for me on any WP site in any version of WP; it produces an Error 403 and the menu isn't deleted.

Can anyone recommend the best workaround?

Thanks very much in advance for any help with this.

Patty

Comment: This works for me just fine. If you experience it consistently I would suggest to look for common link in your server environment or extensions used.

Comment: WP 403s are most frequently indicative of server misconfiguration; I'd recommend skimming your server's error and access logs to try and track down the source. Are you able to add new menus and add and remove menu items? A possible work-around would be to manually remove the menu from the database, but it would be better to rectify the source of the symptom as it may be causing other issues, as well.